# sometimes forked_pid never returns 0

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import os

parent_pid = os.getpid()
print "[parent] starts PID: %d" % (parent_pid, )

forked_pid = os.fork()
if forked_pid == 0:
    print "[child] child process can't use os.fork() PID, since it's %d" % (forked_pid, )
    print "[child] but it can reevaluate os.getpid() to get it's own PID: %d" % (os.getpid(), )
else:
    print "[parent] parent process have created child with PID: %d" % (forked_pid, )
```

[image: output]

If I don't put breakpoint at line 6(`forked_pid = os.fork()`) - I get log from child process but if I debug - forked_pid is never equal to 0.

Reason I started looking into this.

```
p = Process(target=self.run_threaded_io, args=(additional_threads,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

I had this code, where log messages from `run_threaded_io` would never print - and that's because

```
class Popen(object):

    def __init__(self, process_obj):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        self.returncode = None

        self.pid = os.fork()
        if self.pid == 0:
            if 'random' in sys.modules:
                import random
                random.seed()
            code = process_obj._bootstrap()
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stderr.flush()
            os._exit(code)
```

if pid is not 0 - `process_obj._bootstrap()` this never happens - which was internally going to call `run` on `target` i.e. `run_threaded_io` and join on main process (`p.join()`) never completes. and I was running into timeout.

Comment: What happens if you run this from the command line (ie not through pycharm)?

Comment: Also, please include the code in the question body, not as a screenshot

Comment: If i don't debug even through pycharm i.e. let it run - I get logs from child process i.e forked_pid==0 . But only if i debug, I don't enter that else block.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the parent process doesn't wait for child execution. So the parent will execute completely and exit without showing any result of the child execution.
You can use `os.wait()` for waiting for the child to execute completely.

Comment: tried doing that it waits indefinitely and code never completes.